# Can we use timer trigger azure function in ADF

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to use timer trigger azure function in ADF?
I cannot find any link from Microsoft azure.

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem? If you find a good solution, you can write the answer below your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ADF cannot directly use `Timer trigger function`.

But you can create [schedule triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) in Azure Data Factory first:

[image]

Then create a new `Http Trigger Function`, and write the logic originally written in `Time Trigger Function` in `Time Trigger Function`. Then use the Http trigger function in ADF.

For how to use azure function in ADF, you can refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer function and use it in [**`Data Factory pipeline`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity)

> The Azure Function activity allows you to run Azure Functions in a
> Data Factory pipeline. To run an Azure Function, you need to create a
> linked service connection and an activity that specifies the Azure
> Function that you plan to execute.

Comment: will it be similar to creating HTTP trigger and using it in ADF.